# Fluent wait doesnt do any polling

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, wait, fluent

I have come across an answer on SO, where two approaches of Fluent wait were shared out of those only 1 does polling other doesn't.

**First:**

```
List<WebElement> eList = null;
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

            eList  = (List<WebElement>) wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, List<WebElement>>() {
                public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver driver) {
                    return driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpression)));
                }
            });
```

**Second:**

Just change following, in #1

```
eList = (List<WebElement>) wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(xpathExpression)));
```

Second 1 does polling first doesn't. Also prints in console that it tried for 30 seconds with interval of 5 seconds

I am not worrying about why it is not printing in console, my problem is

1. Scenario 2 - prints in console but failed to find the element however element was always there.
2. Scenario 1 -  does exact reverse i.e. it prints nothing in console about polling but able to find element instantly, only when element was already there in DOM. Which means it fails when polling is required.

Now I am end up using both, sometimes #1 and sometimes #2.

There is no preference I only expect since it is fluent wait it should behave like that.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

in your first scenario polling is not happening because you are returning a non null value and this is because
1. findElements() method returns a list of all WebElements, or an empty list if nothing matches and
2. until() method will wait until the condition evaluates to a value that is neither null nor false.

so due to first, you can return null to keep polling until desired element is found (which is when you get the size of list greater than zero)
you can try below code

```
eList  = (List<WebElement>) wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, List<WebElement>>() {
            public List<WebElement> apply(WebDriver driver) {
                List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathExpression));
                if(list.size()==0){
                    return null;
                }else{
                    return list;
                }
            }
        });
```

in second scnario: for ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator) ,an expectation for checking that there is at least one element present on a web page.

Comment: Once returned `null` why it would keep on polling? It's not a for loop.